# Unreal Engine 4 how to build specific pak file separately of the main app

Tags: c#

Unreal Engine 4 how to build specific pak file separately of the main app?

i did this Open Unreal Engine 4 and open your project.
Navigate to the "File" menu and select "Package Project -> Build Configuration -> Shipping".
Once the project is built, navigate to the "File" menu and select "Package Project -> Windows -> Windows (64-bit)".
In the "Package Project" window, deselect all the options other than "Pak (Windows)".
Click the "Package" button to create the Pak file but I can't "unselect" things in Package Project Window